# How do the French people typically say, 'has had its moment'?

Tags: anglais, oral

'Our sea resort hotel has had its moment. But our profits have suffered after that, and it's really put the owner in a bad mood. Well, it was good while it lasted. But never mind that now.'

I was watching an American TV drama program on Netflix and I remember hearing a line like above. I want to find out if there exists French expressions resembling 'has had its moment'. Its meaning is like saying that the hotel was prosperous and famous for a while and it bathed in a spotlight but it has now passed its peak.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that no expression as concise exists in French; the one used below is a fixed expression;

- Il a eu ses moments de gloire.
- Notre hôtel en bord de mer a eu ses moments de gloire. Mais les revenus qu'en tirent les propriétaires ont diminué et cela nous rend malheureux. Enfin, tant que ça a duré ça aura été pour le mieux. Mais n'y pensons plus maintenant.

If you are talking about a unique period of that type, this is also idiomatic;

- Il a eu son heure de gloire.

Comment: Thank you sir or Ms. If you wouldn't mind, could you show how your propositions are included in the whole sentences for my better understanding?

Answer (score 2):

As @con-gras-tue-les-chiens commented, the most common idiom is ***[heure(s) de gloire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/heure_de_gloire)***.

[image]

Here is then a possible translation with slight changes to stay idiomatic:

> Notre hôtel, sur la côte, **a connu ses heures de gloire** puis son patron a commencé a sérieusement faire la gueule car la rentabilité n'était plus au rendez-vous. Bon, c'était bien tant que ça marchait mais aujourd'hui, on tourne la page.